# List - Template? What can we do with it

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

See the picture below to understand.

I will be having 'tags' which will be different depending on what the tag is about.
It could be double sliders, one slider, one slider + a selector. 
How do I use these in a list tpl? Or should I "Create" my 'list' system into container with scrollable set to true?

BTW what is in the picture is static and non working, it's a visual representation for demo.

Using sencha touch 2.2 on sencha architect.

[image: Exemple]

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2/

Comment: You should post it has an answer, it's exactly what I needed. Thank you